# Application force-closed when setting two onClickListeners

Tags: android, onclick, listeners

All of the code below works just as desired.  That is, until I attempt to add a second onClickListener to another image.  The code I am trying to add, and where I am trying to add it is listed as comments in the code below.  Does anyone see anything that I'm missing here?  I feel as though there shouldn't be any problems with this extra implementation.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
ImageView mImage;
//ImageView journal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mImage = (ImageView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.Floaterimg);
    //journal = (ImageView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.journbtn);

    //journal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //@Override
        //public void onClick (View v) {
            //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
                            //SecondActivity.class);
            //startActivity(i);
        //}
    //});

    final Handler randomizer = new Handler();
    final Runnable rrandomizer = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
                               LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*2000 + 1);
            params.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*3000 + 1); 

            mImage.setLayoutParams(params);

            randomizer.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
    rrandomizer.run();

    mImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int numClicks = 0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            numClicks++;
            if(numClicks > 5) {

                Bitmap bitmap = 
                                     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                                     R.drawable.ic_launcher);     
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new 
                                                  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); 
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
                                                             SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("picture", b);

                }
            }

        });
}
```

};

Edit:

Errors from the logcat after pressing the button:

```
10-18 14:17:32.529: E/InputDispatcher(17677): Event_report_payload: Failed to write keypress event to kernel, error = 5
10-18 14:17:32.529: E/dhcpcd(7483): open_udp_socket: No such device
10-18 14:17:32.549: E/dhcpcd(7483): open_socket: No such file or directory
10-18 14:17:32.549: E/dhcpcd(7483): send_raw_packet: No such file or directory
10-18 14:17:32.609: E/InputDispatcher(17677): Event_report_payload: Failed to write keypress event to kernel, error = 5
10-18 14:17:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(26780): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-18 14:17:32.759: E/Monkey(26780): exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg (Permission denied)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780): exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg (Permission denied)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1664)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:945)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3719)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at com.example.inkuesttest.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:18)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1628)
10-18 14:17:32.809: E/AndroidRuntime(26780):    ... 11 more
10-18 14:17:32.829: E/AndroidRuntime(26780): exception :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg (Permission denied)
10-18 14:17:32.869: E/ActivityManager(17677): set systemprop back to original value~
```

Edit:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
//line18
    byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("picture");
//end line18

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
}
```

Comment: please include LOGCAT output or at least the error message logcat produces

Comment: Have you double checked that `journbtn` is the `id` of an `ImageView` inside of `activity_main.xml`? Also, make sure that `SecondActivity` is declared in `manifest.xml`. If those don't work then please post your logcat from the crash.

Comment: if I add startActivity(intent); to the end of "Intent intent" (at the bottom) the SecondActivity has no problem launching.  journbtn is indeed the id of ImageView inside of activity_main.xml.  I will upload the logcat in just a second.

Comment: I've edited the question with information about the logcat... albeit probably not that helpful :\

Comment: Uncomment those lines that were causing a problem and run again then get the full logcat

Comment: done, just now, see edit

Comment: The problem is at line 18 of `SecondActivity`...please post the `onCreate()` of that `Activity` and indicate which is line 18.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Your `extras` are `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to access `extras` in your `Intent` but you aren't passing any. You do in the `Intent` below which is why that one works

```
intent.putExtra("picture", b);
```

but you don't do this in your other `onClick()`. You will either make sure that you are sending `extras` or to be safe do a `null` check in your `SecondActivity` with something like

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  //line18
  if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
  {
      byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("picture");
  }
```

Then of course you will need to handle the lines below that if it is `null`.

**Edit**

If the two `Button`s will do generally the same thing then you can [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845181/onclick-method-issue/15845248#15845248) to use the same method for both. Then you just `switch` on the `id` of the `View` to use different code depending on which was clicked. Something like

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   // arg0 is an ugly name for a param so I changed it to v
       switch (v.getId())
       {
           case (R.id.Floaterimg):
              // do stuff if this image is clicked;
              break;
           case (R.id.journbtn):
              // do stuff if this image is clicked;
              break;
       }
}
```

then put common code such as your `Intent` outside of the `switch` statement.

Comment: what if I want the picture to be saved there after I click the other image five times, as done in the other intent?  Also, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Then just use the same logic as in the other one if that is working for you.

Comment: If I put the bitmap process in the first intent, the image will always be there, though.  How do I make it so that the image is stored in SecondActivity, permanently, but only after pressing the second button 5 times?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand you but I guess you can pass an `extra` to `SecondActivity` to tell it to use a certain image based on the `View` pressed and then do the processing in `SecondActivity` based on the `extra` it receives.

Comment: I also have added some extra information in the edit to my answer that can help clean up the code a little.

Comment: I just mean that I want the image that appears in second activity after the button is pressed 5 times to STAY there permanently.  I do not want it to disappear when I back out of second activity.  Excuse my ignorance, but I am fairly new to developing for android.  Thank you for you help!

Comment: It can't stay there after you back out of the `Activity`. You will have to set it in the other `Activity` also. Once you back out of an `Activity` its `View`s are destroyed

Comment: is there a way to get the status of "int numclicks" for the Image's onClickListener in the Second Activity?  I could set the image in the second activity based on it's status.

Comment: The easiest way would be to pass it as an `extra` in an `Intent`. But I think you may be missing something here. You can't have both `Activities` active at the same time. One will be in the background.

Comment: the second activity is meant to function as a kind of "score sheet" for things done in the first activity.  I want users to go back and forth between activities to see what they have done.  Clicking on the image 5 times gives a record of having done so in the next activity, but I want them to more things in the first activity as well, so they can keep "score" of what they've done as they go.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes but you may want to keep this data in a DB or in `static` variables in a separate class

Comment: I will have to study more about these.  Thank you for the advice

Comment: another quick question while on the topic, actually.  Would it be better to use shared preferences to store these ints?