# Media Player won't play the sound in button click method

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, media

I have 3 buttons and they are supposed to play 3 different sounds. When I used 3 separate onclicks methods in oncreate method it worked properly, but I wanted to clean the code a little, so I implemented OnClickListener to acvtivity and moved the onclick methods down. But now, media players don't play the sounds. How can I make sure media players work?

```
public class Play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    MediaPlayer mpPlay1,mpPlay2,mpPlay3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play);


    Button bPlay1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button bPlay2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button bPlay3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        int resIdPlay1 = getResources().getIdentifier("play1", "raw", getPackageName());
        int resIdPlay2 = getResources().getIdentifier("play2", "raw", getPackageName());
        int resIdPlay3 = getResources().getIdentifier("play3", "raw", getPackageName());

        mpPlay1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resIdPlay1);
        mpPlay2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resIdPlay2);
        mpPlay3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resIdPlay3);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            mpPlay1.start();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            mpPlay2.start();
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            mpPlay3.start();
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't implemented the listener on the `Buttons` yet, or at least haven't shown it. You should have something like

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

inside your `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`. You would need this for each `Button`.

Since you are trying to clean up your code and make it more condensed, you can set the `onClick()` in your xml.

I have explained it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319711/android-eclipse-which-is-the-best-way-to-add-a-button/18319759#18319759) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845181/onclick-method-issue/15845248#15845248)

[The Button docs also cover this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately the problem is not that. I added it, it is still not working.

Comment: Can you define "not working"? Are you getting any errors? Also, edit and post that part of the code and how you added it.

Comment: I editted the code. I am not getting any errors. It is like mediaplayer is null in onclick method.

Comment: You still haven't shown where you set the `listener`s like in my second line of code. If the `MediaPlayer` was returning `null` then it would crash.

Comment: You're welcome. Please edit the OP to take the button declarations out of the original code or it may be confusing to others. When you edit, you should leave the original code intact and just edit the new code separately.